# How to rightfully connect dockerized api and frontend (next's application with strapi)

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, next.js, strapi

Since a few days I am trying to deploy my next.js site with strapi as api in a dockerized environment.

So far I already found out that my frontend is not able to use the "normal" DNS and therefore will resolve the api url to the internal docker ip. This is no problems at frist, however both my docker application (frontend and backend) are running behind a Hynix proxy using https. To achieve that I am using  [jwilder nginx-proxy](https://hub.docker.com/r/jwilder/nginx-proxy) proxy on my server.

The problem now is that since it is using the internal ip I can't use https for the api url. it works for the build with http without any problem, however as soon as I try to load content via axios for example, it will throw up (surprise surprise) a mixed content error.

I think I am missing the final hint how to solve the whole mess.

Here are my Dockerbuild files:

**Nextjs Frontend**

```
# Install dependencies only when needed
FROM node:14-alpine AS deps
# Check https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/tree/b4117f9333da4138b03a546ec926ef50a31506c3#nodealpine to understand why libc6-compat might be needed.
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile

# Rebuild the source code only when needed
FROM node:14-alpine AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules
ENV NODE_ENV=production
ENV NEXT_PUBLIC_STRAPI_API_URL=http://<myapi.com>:1337
RUN yarn build

# Production image, copy all the files and run next
FROM node:14-alpine AS runner
WORKDIR /app

ENV NODE_ENV=production  
ENV process=production
ENV NEXT_PUBLIC_STRAPI_API_URL=http://<myapi.com>:1337

RUN addgroup -g 1001 -S nodejs
RUN adduser -S nextjs -u 1001

# You only need to copy next.config.js if you are NOT using the default configuration
# COPY --from=builder /app/next.config.js ./
COPY --from=builder /app/public ./public
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next ./.next
COPY --from=builder /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY --from=builder /app/package.json ./package.json

USER nextjs

EXPOSE 3000

# Next.js collects completely anonymous telemetry data about general usage.
# Learn more here: https://nextjs.org/telemetry
# Uncomment the following line in case you want to disable telemetry.
# ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1

CMD ["yarn", "start"]
```

**API (Strapi) Backend**

```
FROM strapi/base

WORKDIR /backend

COPY ./package.json ./
COPY ./yarn.lock ./

RUN yarn install

COPY . .

ENV NODE_ENV production
ENV CLOUDINARY_NAME <name>
ENV CLOUDINARY_API_KEY <apikey>
ENV CLOUDINARY_API_SECRET <apisec>

RUN yarn build

EXPOSE 1337

CMD ["yarn", "start"]
```

**Docker Compose**

```
version: "3"

services:
  backend:
    image: backend:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "1337:1337"
    volumes:
      - strapidata:/data
    environment:
      VIRTUAL_HOST: <myapi.com>
      LETSENCRYPT_HOST: <myapi.com>
    container_name: <myapi.com>

  frontent:
    image: frontend:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "1338:3000"
    depends_on:
      - backend
    environment:
      VIRTUAL_HOST: <myfrontend.com>
      LETSENCRYPT_HOST: <myfrontend.com>
      NEXT_PUBLIC_STRAPI_API_URL: <myapi.com>:1337
    container_name: <myfrontend.com>

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: webproxy

volumes:
  strapidata:
```

Thanks a lot!

Edit:
so just to clarify, my main problem as described is that when using https:// it won't resolve since my frontend will use the docker dns which will resolve the https:// request to the internal ip which doesn't accept https// since the ssl certificate is provided via the ngnix reverse proxy. So I need either an solution on how to work with the internal network without getting a mixed error content (trying to get data from my Webbrowser) or to resolve the api call using a public DNS!

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the problem, but you'd normally use Docker's internal DNS instead of IPs. E.g. to make a request to your backend you'd use an URL like `http://backend/foo/bar`…

Comment: That what I tried, however as described this will throw a mixed content error.

Comment: Ah, so your doing the request from within the browser. In this case you just need to publish both frontend and backend through your reverse proxy and use the external URLs (no IPs anywhere)… (you don't gain much from compose here)

Comment: Can you give me an example? Not sure how to do that? As you can see that is actually what I did. However I can't use the https: url since it will nor resolve using the internal network

Comment: I think you're probably mixing up some aspects here… First, all DNS records should resolve to your publicly accessible reverse proxy IP(s). That's the one that does TLS termination. At this stage this has nothing yet to do with Docker at all, and nothing should *"resolve using the internal network"*. The reverse proxy then connects to your Docker services. Don't know why you want to add an additional nginx proxy, it shouldn't be necessary. Just publish one TCP port for each backend and frontend and configure your reverse proxy to connect there.

Comment: Thanks. This comment helped a lot. Also figured out my error. I literally set the name of my container equal to the url. Please don't ask why. Rookie mistake. Works now! Thanks for your input!